# A moving rectangle becomes stuck after hitting the edge of the window

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I created a rectangle in the middle of the window, and used key 'w', 's', 'a', 'd', to move it. My problem is every time the rectangle hits the edge of the window is becomes stuck and cannot move any more.

```
import pygame, sys, time
from pygame.locals import *

class Tile:
    bcolor = pygame.Color('black')
    rcolor = pygame.Color('white')

    def __init__(self, surface):
        self.surface = surface
        self.size = 30
        self.x = self.surface.get_width()//2 - self.size//2
        self.y = self.surface.get_height()//2 - self.size//2
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, self.size, self.size)
        self.speed = 10
        self.rcolor = Tile.rcolor
        self.bcolor = Tile.bcolor

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(self.surface, self.rcolor, self.rect)

    def moveup(self):
        if self.rect.top < self.speed:
            self.speed = self.rect.top
        self.rect.move_ip(0, -self.speed)

    def movedown(self):
        maxbottom = self.surface.get_height()
        if maxbottom - self.rect.bottom < self.speed:
            self.speed = maxbottom - self.rect.bottom
        self.rect.move_ip(0,self.speed)

    def moveleft(self):
        if self.rect.left < self.speed:
            self.speed = self.rect.left
        self.rect.move_ip(-self.speed, 0)

    def moveright(self):
        maxright = self.surface.get_width()
        if maxright - self.rect.right < self.speed:
            self.speed = maxright - self.rect.right
        self.rect.move_ip(self.speed, 0)

    def handlekeydown(self, key):
        if key == K_w:
            self.moveup()
        if key == K_s:
            self.movedown()
        if key == K_a:
            self.moveleft()
        if key == K_d:
            self.moveright()
    def update(self):
        self.surface.fill(self.bcolor)
        self.draw()
def main():
    pygame.init()
    pygame.key.set_repeat(20, 20)
    surfacesize = (500,400)
    title = 'Practice'
    framedelay = 0.02
    surface = pygame.display.set_mode(surfacesize, 0, 0)
    pygame.display.set_caption(title)
    tile = Tile(surface)
    gameover = False
    tile.draw()
    pygame.display.update()

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == KEYDOWN and not gameover:
                tile.handlekeydown(event.key)
            tile.update()
            pygame.display.update()
            time.sleep(framedelay)
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just look at this piece of code:

```
def moveup(self):
    if self.rect.top < self.speed:
        self.speed = self.rect.top
    self.rect.move_ip(0, -self.speed)
```

Once you move to the top of the screen, `self.rect.top` becomes `0`, which is smaller than `self.speed`, so the condition of the `if` statement is `True` and in the next line you set `self.speed` to `0`, hence all your `move_ip` calls won't move the `Rect` (because `self.speed` is now `0`).

If you want to prevent the `Rect` from leaving the screen, better just use [`clamp_ip`](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.clamp_ip):

```
...
def moveup(self):
    self.rect.move_ip(0, -self.speed)

def movedown(self):
    self.rect.move_ip(0,self.speed)

def moveleft(self):
    self.rect.move_ip(-self.speed, 0)

def moveright(self):
    self.rect.move_ip(self.speed, 0)

def handlekeydown(self, key):
    if key == K_w:
        self.moveup()
    if key == K_s:
        self.movedown()
    if key == K_a:
        self.moveleft()
    if key == K_d:
        self.moveright()
    self.rect.clamp_ip(pygame.display.get_surface().get_rect())
 ...
```

(There are some other issues with your code, but that's another topic.)